# How to get the the most recent queries in Oracle DB

Tags: database, oracle

I have a web application and I doubt some others have deleted some records manually. Upon enquiry nobody is admitting the mistakes. How to find out at what time those records were deleted ??  Is it possible to get the history of delete queries ?

Comment: You would want to use Log Miner to go through the archived logs to find the delete statements that you are interested in.  That can be quite time consuming if you aren't sure when the deletes happened.  It is possible that they would still be cached in v$sql but that is not certain.  And unless the queries used literals, you would not know the bind values used when the queries were executed.

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to v$ view then you can use the following query to get it. It contains the time as FIRST_LOAD_TIME column.

```
select *
from  v$sql v
where upper(sql_text) like '%DELETE%';
```

Answer (score 2):

If flashback query is enabled for your database (try it with `select * from table as of timestamp sysdate - 1`) then it may be possible to determine the exact time the records were deleted. Use the `as of timestamp` clause and adjust the timestamp as necessary to narrow down to a window where the records still existed and did not exist anymore.

For example

```
select *
from table
as of timestamp to_date('21102016 09:00:00', 'DDMMYYYY HH24:MI:SS')
where id = XXX; -- indicates record still exists

select *
from table
as of timestamp to_date('21102016 09:00:10', 'DDMMYYYY HH24:MI:SS')
where id = XXX; -- indicates record does not exist

-- conclusion: record was deleted in this 10 second window
```